# "Majority" is to "plurality" as "minority" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

This analogy may not be quite accurate but I think I can get my point across with it.

I was reviewing some [obesity statistics](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/overwt.htm):

- Obese: 35.9%
- Overweight but not obese: 33.3%
- Neither overweight nor obese: 30.8%

There is no majority. "Obesity" is the plurality. Is there a specific term for "neither overweight nor obese" as the smallest minority?

Comment: I don't think your definition of *plurality* (the largest of several contingents, none of which constitutes an actual majority) would be generally understood in the UK.

Comment: I'm more familiar with _relative majority_ as opposed to _absolute_ or _outright majority_.

Comment: Also, "asparagus" is to "calculus" as "Brazil" is to what?

Comment: In politics, it's "the also rans". I don't know about fat people, though.

Comment: "Singularity"? Not what you were asking, but my best answer for just what your title is asking. Also meant to be a humorous answer, not a serious one.

Comment: Is 'plurality' used in the 'number of results in modal interval' sense outside (US) politics? It's confusingly polysemous in any case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the trouble here is that it *isn't* '“Majority” to “plurality.”' In discussing proportions, majority is the counterpart to minority; the whole is divided into two unequal parts, and thus one part is greater than half and the other smaller. If a majority exists, by definition no plurality can exist. At the same time, one can view a plurality as simply the "first among minorities," the largest among various fractions that do not muster 50%.

One would need to employ a phrase to describe a proportion which is neither a majority nor a plurality. The part of the population which is neither overweight nor obese could be the *smallest proportion* of the population, or the *least fraction* or the *littlest part*, or some such formulation.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a problem with the way you have structured the concept. *Plurality*, as you use it, is usually [defined](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/plurality) by most online dictionaries in political terms

> the number of votes that a politician or party gets in an election that is more than any other but is less than an absolute majority

It is determined based on two disjunctive characteristics:

- largest single group, but
- not a majority

The *smallest minority* is just that - the smallest group.  There is not another characteristic that makes it analogous to *plurality*.

In fact, the term *minority* itself poses a problem.  It is generally [defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minority) in the context of two groups

> the smaller in number of two groups constituting a whole; specifically: a group having less than the number of votes necessary for control

Further, the term *minority* can encompass more than one group when there are more than three categories. Which of those (or which combination of those) is of interest depends on the context of the categorization.  In social situations, there are often a number of *minorities* identified based on a variety of characteristics differing from the *majority*. Further, a number of political or social *minorities* may coalesce to form a *plurality*.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to describe what relationship you see between "majority" and "plurality" before you could say what the corresponding word is for "minority".

Normally we say that the opposite of "majority" is "minority", not "plurality". The only way I can see to relate majority and plurality is to say that a majority is the largest group or block and is over 50%, while a plurality is the largest group or block and is under 50%. But to make a similar relationship with "minority" ... what? It's meaningless to talk about a minorities that are over 50% and those that are under 50%. If you're over 50% you're not a minority.

If you're looking for a word that means "the smallest minority", hmm, I don't know any single word for that. If there is one, I don't think it's widely used. I think the simplest thing to do is simply call it "the smallest group".

Comment: I don't see any claim by OP or elsewhere here that "majority" and "plurality" are opposites.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, I guess, singularity.

EDIT: I accidentally considered only the title question. Now having read your entire post, it seems to me that your definition of "plurality" (= manyhood, multitude) is not correct. There is no specific term I know of which means "largest group (but not majority)", nor for the opposite (smallest group). So, as far as the terms I know are concerned, you'll have to settle for "largest group"/"largest fraction" and "smallest group"/"smallest faction".

Comment: No fear, though. You're still a GoodCommunist!

Comment: I just typed this as a (joking) comment to the question, then I scrolled down to see that somebody actually answered with it. I too, only considered the title question.

Answer (score 0):

Both the terms majority and minority describes a mass of people in most of the cases. While the term majority describes more number of people, the term minority describes less number of people compared to those in majority. Both these terms cannot be compared to plurality and singularity. however it can be a coincidence if the no. of people in minority are 1.

Answer (score 0):

Original question: "Majority" is to "plurality" as "minority" is to what?"

I had the exact same question, and studying the answers by others, I came to the insight that the correct answer is actually "smallest subset".

First, I think that a better definition of "plurality" is: the largest subset of a kind. In the example of the OP, 3 weight categories are considered, and each category corresponds to a subset of all people. The plurality is the largest of these, hence the obese.

Now, in most definitions I have seen, the definition of "plurality" is defined as the largest minority, where minority is defined as a subset that's less than 1/2 of all elements considered. However, if we just look at all subsets, and one of them turns out to be a majority (hence more than 1/2 of all considered elements), then it is still a plurality with my preferred definition (there isn't an exception to consider). On the other hand, if *more than* 2 subsets are considered, and we'd ignore the majority, is it useful to talk about a plurality as the largest of the remaining minorities? In that case, if there *is* a majority, the largest minority can not be more than 1/4 of all the elements considered (please, check). But how is that relevant? This seems futile and rather confusing.

So, I think that the better **definition of plurality is simply the largest subset of a kind**, as proposed.

Now, let's look again at the analogy

majority : minority = plurality : *unknown*.

Consider first that if there are only 2 subsets, they're either both equal in size, and there is no majority, nor a minority (since the definition of majority is that it ought to be more than 1/2, and a minority ought to be less than 1/2). But if there is a majority, there is certainly a minority (the rest), and the plurality equals the majority.

In fact, we saw earlier that the majority, if it exists, *always* equals the plurality, not just in the case of 2 subsets.

Consider next that if there are *more than* 2 subsets, then considering majority vs. minority, we're considering at most 1 subset vs. at least 2 subsets. This is an asymmetrical situation. In particular, there can be only *at most* 1 majority, but there will be *more than* 1 minority.  However, since there are more than 1 minority (and if there is no majority), then looking at the largest minority makes sense and that is the most common situation.

In this case, we can still talk about the *smallest* minority, which is simply the smallest subset; but it is nonsensical to talk about the *smallest majority* (you don't need a second term to describe the same unique thing, *majority*).

Let's translate the analogy to

"subset > 1/2 of elements" : "largest subset" = "subset < 1/2 of elements" : *unknown*.

We want to solve for *unknown*. My proposed candidate is "smallest subset". Let's see how this fits.

First, in case of 2 subsets, we see that the relationship on the left expresses the identity, if there *is* a majority. But if there *isn't* a majority (both subsets are equal), then we also know that the largest subset *equals* the smallest subset. In both cases, we can thus write the valid analogy:

"subset > 1/2 of all elements" : "largest subset" = "subset < 1/2 of all elements" : "smallest subset".

Second, in case that there are *more than* 2 subsets, we need to reconsider the meaning of the analogy expressed.

**a.)** If there is a *majority* (*unique*), then the *largest subset* is *equal* to *the majority*. **b.)** If there is *no majority*, then all subsets are minorities, and the *largest subset* equals *the largest minority*.

Let's see how we can translate this into the right side terms, mutatis mutandis:

**a.)** If there is a *minority* (*not unique*), and then the *smallest subset* is *equal* to *a minority*. **b.)** If there is *no minority*, then TRUE, and *whatever*.

**Note.** The b.) leg is seemingly collapsing here. However, if there are more than 2 subsets, it is *impossible* for there *not* to be a minority. Namely, in this case, all subsets should be at least 1/2 of all elements (no minority), but with at least 3 sets, this can't be true (unless the subsets are overlapping, but we are implicitly assuming they don't). This means that the b.) leg is TRUE by default (and I just asserted that with "TRUE", but copied the format of the earlier b.) leg for the case of 2 subsets. Consider the definition of an if-then assertion! In particular, the statement "if A then B" is true if A is *not* true, such as here.

In particular, in the analogy we can use for *whatever* = "the *smallest subset* equals the EMPTY set" (this is untrue, but that doesn't matter; it fits the analogy!)

So, surprisingly, for more than 2 subsets, the analogy *can* include the b.) legs as well! The a.) legs would work with  = "smallest subset", if we ignore the slight asymmetry between majority and minority.

Hence, the best candidate for *unknown* equals "smallest subset", yielding the analogy

majority : minority = plurality : smallest subset.

Comment: The question is infelicitous; 'plurality' is ill-defined and as @bib says rarely if ever used in the 'largest grouping when this comprises less than 50% of the population' sense, rather, **in politics**, the size of such a group. Best left unanswered and CV-d.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think anybody so far understands the question (either that or I don't).

I think what the OP is asking is, what is the word for a minority that is not the largest minority (not a plurality). He wants a word that makes clear that the minority of which he speaks (if he could find the word for it) is not the plurality. Example: Say the demographics of a state are: 45% Caucasian, 25% African-American, 20% Asian, 10% Native American. The word "minority" applies to all groups. Is there a word that only applies to the non-plurality minorities? A word that makes clear that this particular minority is not a plurality? A word that you can use to describe all of those minorities except Caucasians (which are a plurality).

I don't know of such a word, but I'd like to.

Comment: I think it's clear that the OP is interested in understanding the analogy as is posted. As with all analogies, if the answer is unknown, it requires some creativity to come to an answer. I've tried my best to come up with a motivation for my answer.